# Is it possible to create a log of all `svn update` calls

Tags: svn, logging, svn-update

I am wondering whether there is any way to:

1. On any existing repo, see a log of all users that have updated (And the revision they updated to).
   or
2. With extra configuration, create a repository where [1] will be possible from then on.

I don't think 1 is possible but thought I would ask anyway.
I am surprised that 2 doesn't appear to be possible, I would have assumed before attempting this that there would be a hook available but all of them appear to be for commiting only.

I should clarify that I want the updates to be captured by the remote repository automatically, with no alterations to the clients.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How do you access your repository? If you're using the WebDAV module (ie, HTTP or HTTPS urls), you should be able to extract this information from the Apache logs. You might have to post-process the data to attach revision number.

If you're using svnserve over SSH, then you can create a wrapper program for svnserve that logs accesses. There may also be a log option for direct svnserve, but since I don't like using it, I haven't looked.

But all this begs the question: why do you want to track this? Subversion tracks revisions on a per-file bases, and [mixed revisions are normal](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.mixedrevs).